# при работе кода возникает ошибка

Tags: c#

у меня есть класс:

```
public class Update_Quantity
    {
        public class Stock
        {
            public string offer_id { get; set; }
            public int product_id { get; set; }
            public int stock { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public List<Stock> stocks { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

потом я создаю эти два класса

```
Update_Quantity.Root root = new Update_Quantity.Root();
Update_Quantity.Stock stock = new Update_Quantity.Stock();
```

после этого я записываю в них данные

```
stock.offer_id = Checked_Articles[i];
            stock.product_id = ID_Item[i];
            stock.stock =Convert.ToInt32(List_item_MC.rows[i].quantity);
            root.stocks[i].offer_id = stock.offer_id; // здесь ошибка System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр Update_Quantity.Root.stocks.get вернул null.
            root.stocks[i].product_id = stock.product_id;
            root.stocks[i].stock = stock.stock;
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: сложно найти ошибку в чужом коде, не зная что за ошибка. в будущем указывайте что за ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Перед тем, как заполнять коллекцию, необходимо ее создать:

```
root.stocks = new List<Update_Quantity.Stock>();
```